# java testing database structure : can't find an appropriate framework

Tags: java, database, testing

I'm searching a way to validate in java that the database schemas are ok, default values ok, triggers ok as well.
I've found a lot of framework to test db interactions but can't find something that coould allow me to test for tables and schema.
Is there any kind of framework for that ?
It will be used in if possible maven to block deployment if the db has not been sync'd.

Thanks

Comment: Could you write something wrapping/extending a JDBC driver (such as postgres JDBC - https://jdbc.postgresql.org/)? Here's an overview: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-141217.html

Comment: Yes I could I was just wondering if some framework might exist as I can't believe that is not a recurrent need. But if it comes to that yes I will do that

Comment: Are you manually migrating schema changes or are you using JPA?

Comment: not really manual but as we have different systems interacting with the database (PHP based and java based ) JPA in this case is not responsible for the migration of db. That s why I wanted a way to make sure that the db is compliant.

Comment: Could DBUnit be something for you? http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) offers that functionality (checking database state) and a lot more, being mainly used to manage database changes regardless of other technologies (such as JPA) used.

It also plugs into maven's build cycle.

Comment: Thanks yes seems like liquibase does what I want !